# For loop not properly calculating sum of rows

Tags: excel, vba

Below is my code, purpose is to create a range of data automatically and then changing the text under column B to blue if the row sum is less than 550000.

This part is for creating the range:

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range
Dim ranged_select As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("MonthlySales")
Set StartCell = sht.Range("C2")

'Find Last Row and Column
lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
lastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'selecting the range of values and assigning to variable
Set ranged_select = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
```

This part is for getting the sum of each of the rows and then changing the corresponding "Region" to blue if the value is less than 550000.

```
Dim i As Long

For i = 2 To lastRow
    If Application.Sum(ranged_select.Rows(i)) < 550000 Then
        Sheet2.Cells(i, "B").Font.Color = vbBlue
    End If
Next
```

However as you can see in my results, the fourth row was changed to blue when it should have been row two only. I calculated the sum after I ran my code so it wasn't the problem. What is wrong with the  second part of my code? I am having trouble figuring out the issue.
[image]

Comment: Is it your intention to colour the text *every_single_time* through the loop if the total is under the target value? Would it not be better, to sum the range, then set the colour just once?

Comment: `ranged_select.Rows(i)` is not the same row on the sheet as `Cells(i, "B")`. If it helps you, `Debug.Print ranged_select.Rows(i).Address`... Plus, your code never considers the first row of `ranged_select`, since `i` begins at 2.

Comment: You can get the desired outcome with `Conditional Formatting`. This can update the font color automatically, without the need to run a macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for the fact you are not including column B in your ranged_select but you are including the last column which is a row sum already, and you are starting at row 2. I would use conditional formatting personally, but here is one way that shows indexing according to your range variable. This keeps code close to what you have written.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ColourCells()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastColumn As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range
    Dim ranged_select As Range

    Set sht = Worksheets("MonthlySales")
    Set StartCell = sht.Range("C2")

    'Find Last Row and Column
    lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    'selecting the range of values and assigning to variable
    Set ranged_select = sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(lastRow, lastColumn))
    
    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To ranged_select.Rows.Count
    
        If Application.Sum(ranged_select.Cells(i, ranged_select.Columns.Count)) < 550000 Then

            sht.Cells(ranged_select.Cells(i, 1).Row, 2).Font.Color = vbBlue
            
        End If
    
    Next

End Sub
```